# Thunderbird login to Gmail with OAuth2 fails with "secure connection failed" - how to complete the login?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, oauth2

From 30 May 2022 we will be required to use OAuth2, not normal passwords, to log in to Gmail accounts. [How will this Google announcement affect Thunderbird?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1369872) So, I've tried several times to change the Gmail accounts in my Thunderbird instance (versions 91.7.0, 91.7.1 and 91.8.1 at different times, on Kubuntu Linux 20.04) to use OAuth2.

However, when I try the required steps:

- Account Settings > Server Settings > Authentication method = OAuth2
- Remove existing password
- Restart Thunderbird

after the expected OAuth2 login pages (email address, then password, then "Mozilla Thunderbird Email want to access your Google Account), I get an unexpected "**Secure connection failed**" page.

> Secure connection failed
> This could be a problem with the server's configuration, or it could be someone trying to impersonate the server.
> If you have connected to this server successfully in the past, the error may be temporary, and you can try again later.
> Or you can add an exception...

The add an exception link does not do anything. There is no way past this other than closing the dialogue. The authentication is not successful.

The title bar of this dialogue window shows https://192.168.x.x/?code=... with my own IP address. I'm not clear why the OAuth2 process would need to call a web server on the local machine.

Reverting to "Normal password" enables the account to work correctly in Thunderbird, but this won't be possible after 30 May.

Answer (score 12):

In my case this is what fixed it, or appears to (I can't rule out that I made other changes to the system).

I am running a local web server using apache2 with a self-signed ssl certificate, which would be insecure for a public web server and requires a browser exception. The "Secure connection failed" page is what you normally see in Firefox / Thunderbird connecting to such a server.

If I stop apache2:

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2
```

then the Gmail OAuth2 authentication completes and I can receive and send email - starting apache2 again doesn't interfere with this, only with the initial password entry.

**Note:** The same issue would probably occur with any local web server running on the default port 443 (https) or 80 (http) and with a self-signed, expired or invalid ssl certificate, but I haven't tested it with any others. Others have reported that the same problem can occur with nginx.

(I still don't know why a call needs to be made at all to a local web server.)

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. In my case it was Nginx.

Comment: Very frustrating. However, I doubt the self-signed certificate makes any difference. The request probably expects a certain response, and any kind of different behavior will mean it fails. Thunderbird probably tries to bind to port 80.

Comment: XAMPP in my case, stopped Apache and I was able to authenticate

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://superuser.com/a/1722268/295133) answer is correct but with little extension. This behavior can be caused by any application that listens on port 80 on localhost.
On Linux just check what application or service listens on localhost:80. You can run:

```
sudo netstat -plant | grep 80
```

and check which application is in your case and just switch it off.
In my case it was:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1628/nginx: master
```

calling (on Ubuntu):

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

solved problem

Comment: But why in the world should Thunderbird (or is it a browser? from the description in question it is not quite clear) contact anything running on localhost when authenticating to Google?

Comment: As I said in the linked answer "The same issue would probably occur with any local web server". And note it affects port 443 (https) not just port 80 (http).

Comment: @raj I have not found any explanation of why the Google authentication process within the Thunderbird email client should contact localhost.

Comment: @raj It is an embedded browser in Thunderbird, to allow the user to complete the web-based OAuth2 workflow. Near the end of the workflow, the browser is redirected to a localhost URL.

Comment: @gileri What is expected to listen on this localhost URL?

Comment: I think nothing, as I'm pretty sure user-run Thunderbird will not have capabilities to open a low TCP port (80/443 here). Thunderbird surely just detects the HTTP redirection to localhost when nothing listens on TCP/443, but not when there is a web server with an invalid certificate answering.

Answer (score 2):

PAY ATTENTION THUNDERBIRD USERS if GMail OAuth2 appear not working properly.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1373706

It appear that if you have anything responding locally to port 443 thunderbird refuses to login using oauth2 even if the popup credential request is satisfied.

In my case, i had IIS installed and running in my laptop, but i added a bind to https/443 using a self signed certificate (this to test incoming connections using secure protocol). This also interfere with thunderbird, and may led to fail gmail authentication using oauth2 (the only option today).

As far as i have shutted down iis (or removed the https2/443 binding), thunderbird restarted to authenticate properly the gmail IMAP server.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a proxy server running (or simply active) on your machine, this will also interfere with Thunderbird detecting the redirection. In my case, I'm a developer running Fiddler, a web debugger that can act as the default system proxy and start automatically.

Apparently anything on localhost that respondson http port 80 is enough to derail Thunderbird's initial authentication attempt.

Thanks to @JoeP and @MarekPodyma for the clues to look "outside the box".

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar Problem. But it so happened that I also had a self signed certificate that thunderbird didnt like, so I was in a loop of not getting redirected back to my local machine after successfully authenticating with google. Not until I had to temporarily stop apache sever.

```
systemctl stop apache2
```

Login to the account remotely and get redirected back,finish the setup and

```
systemctl start apache2
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: There are already 3 answers that suggest the same solution

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1241063)