# Thunderbird keeps asking for Gmail login

Tags: thunderbird

I use Thunderbird to grab emails from various accounts as POP to keep them on my desktop.  Other gmail accounts work fine, but one of them, pops up this form in a new browser window, every few weeks.  It works fine with the saved password at other times.

- Sign in with Google
  Sign in to continue to Mozilla Thunderbird Email
- Then it does a two-step verification on my mobile.
  I tick the box `Don't ask again on this device` and confirm its me on the mobile.
- Next it confirms in the browser that `this will allow Thunderbird to Read, compose, send and permanently delete all your email from Gmail`

After this, it works for a few weeks and then we go through the same ritual again.

---

The authentication method on Mozilla is OAuth2 with SSL/TSL security.  Note the settings are identical for the other Google account that works flawlessly.

**How can I stop this ?**

Note [this is not the same question and the answers don't apply](https://superuser.com/questions/1722267/thunderbird-login-to-gmail-with-oauth2-fails-with-secure-connection-failed-h)

---

Its not a workspace account.  I do have another client accessing it.  On the mobile, I use Fairmail and access all the same accounts with using IMAP.  Whereas, on the desktop I use POP.  The mobile never fails.  It is only thunderbird, and only on this account.  I have 5 gmail accounts for (different purposes), the other 4 work flawlessly.  I also have a dozen other accounts for the websites/domains I run (non Gmail) and they also work all the time.

I have deleted that profile, once, some months ago, but no luck.  It is a bit tedious to do this as I have many emails organised in nested folders.  And I will have to move them again.

I do use VPN on both the mobile and the desktop, but on both it is on a per app basis and the email apps are excluded.  I had to do this some years ago, because as per the comments, my account got locked (appearing to jump countries instantly), and Google charged a princely sum of $1 to unlock it.  I use ExpressVPN on both the mobile and the desktop.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the problem email profile.  Try that, close Thunderbird, restart, make a new email profile and see if that works

Comment: Is this perhaps a Google Workspace account? Admins can enforce maximum session lifetime there. // Also, do you use _many_ clients to access this particular accounts?

Comment: Check passwords; likely there are *four* for each GMail account -- 2 SMTP, and 2 IMAP. The primary password is one *you* created, the secondary is machine-specific, generated by GMail. Check that those secondary passwords aren't lost or expired, and that they are *different* from those on another PC. BTW, I found that accidentally connecting with VPN active caused my GMail account to be locked -- it appeared my location was in another country.